# Strapi + Postgres: Cannot SELECT from table - syntax error

Tags: postgresql, query

I am using strapi and postgres. I created two collections in strapi called "solutions" and "references".

When I run `\dt` I get the following output:

```
 ...more tables
 public | references                                                 | table | postgres
 public | references_components                                      | table | postgres
 public | references_pages                                           | table | postgres
 public | references_pages_components                                | table | postgres
 public | solutions                                                  | table | postgres
 public | solutions_components                                       | table | postgres
 public | solutions_pages                                            | table | postgres
 public | solutions_pages_components
```

Now I want to run a `SELECT` on table "solutions", which works:
`SELECT * FROM solutions;`

But when I run `SELECT * FROM references;` I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "references"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM references;
```

I already checked if there is a lock, but nothing. Running `\z references` gives the following output:

```
                                   Access privileges
 Schema |    Name    | Type  |     Access privileges     | Column privileges | Policies
--------+------------+-------+---------------------------+-------------------+----------
 public | references | table | postgres=arwdDxt/postgres |                   |
(1 row)
```

What could be wrong? Is there maybe an issue with the table being named "references"? This issue happens on my local machine as well on our staging server, so I do not assume that it is an issue with my local postgres setup.

I also checked priviliges with

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type                                                                                                                                                                   
 FROM   information_schema.table_privileges WHERE  grantee = 'postgres'
```

Which gives this output (scroll to the right):

```
 mytable     | public             | references                                                 | INSERT
 mytable     | public             | references                                                 | SELECT
 mytable     | public             | references                                                 | UPDATE
 mytable     | public             | references                                                 | DELETE
 mytable     | public             | references                                                 | TRUNCATE
 mytable     | public             | references                                                 | REFERENCES
 mytable     | public             | references                                                 | TRIGGER
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the table is named "references", which Postgres apparently does not like. Calling the table "my_references" or "referencess" works.

```
template1=# CREATE TABLE references (id bigint NOT NULL);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "references"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE references (id bigint NOT NULL);
```

This works:

```
template1=# CREATE TABLE referencesss (id bigint NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
```

Comment: "references" is a reserved word, used in the creation of Foreign Keys. 
You should *never* use reserved words to name tables, columns or other objects in your databases.  It /will/ come back to bite you.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the info. I will have to create an issue at strapi that their cms should throw an error when you try to create a collection name "references" (or they should just prefix it).